# Python requests - assigning dict of proxies to requests

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests, proxies

I'm trying to establish connection to https://example.de and I have to use the corporation proxy for that, otherwise the server cannot be reached.

I defined a static dict `proxy_dict` inside of class. Both examples show 2 different initialization methods. One of them is working.

**Example 1**

```
class A:
    proxy_dict = {'http': '192.x.x.x:8080', 'https': '192.x.x.x:8080'}

    def __init__(self):
    ...

    def getData():
        ...
        requests.get('https://example.de/registration', headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, proxies=A.proxy_dict)
        ...
```

As a result, I'm getting the following message:

```
[Error] HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /registration (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))) - aborting ..`.
```

**Example 2**

The only change what I did was `proxy_dict = dict(http='192.x.x.x:8080', https='192.x.x.x:8080')`

The request goes through and no proxy authentication is required.

I would be appreciated if someone could explain me why the example 1 doesn't work. I would like to know what is happening under the hoot. Both initializatons of `proxy_dict` seems to be correct, both are `dict`.

Comment: if that's really your code then, example 2  works because you are using a real IP

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez Sorry, for confusion. I edit the content of my question

Comment: @Joshua, are you saying you _only_ changed from a dict literal (`{ 'http':'192...', etc}`) to a dict constructor _and it worked?_

Comment: If that's really the case, I suspect a transient network problem and I would try the original code again. The two versions ought to be exactly identical, as far as python is concerned.

Comment: @alexis exactly

Comment: I forget to mentioned that I'm using python 3.7.3, requests 2.22

Comment: Try it again or look for other differences (e.g. a typo), the constructor vs. literal difference is a non-issue.